# JSON объект в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

Как это:

```
{
    "item1": {
         "11": {
             "name111": "name",
             "type112": "type"
         },
         "12": {
             "name121": "name",
             "type122": "type"
         }
    },
    "item2": {
         "21": {
             "name211": "name",
             "type212": "type"
         },
         "22": {
             "name221": "name",
             "type222": "type"
         }
    }
}
```

Превратить в это:

```
[
    [
         [
             "name",
             "type"
         ],
         [
             "name",
             "type"
         ]
    ],
    [
         [
            "name",
            "type"
         ],
         [
            "name",
            "type"
         ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: никак. То, что Вы хотите получить, содержит синтактические ошибли.

Comment: Отредактировал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
    "item1": {
         "11": {
             "name111": "name",
             "type112": "type"
         },
         "12": {
             "name121": "name",
             "type122": "type"
         }
    },
    "item2": {
         "21": {
             "name211": "name",
             "type212": "type"
         },
         "22": {
             "name221": "name",
             "type222": "type"
         }
    }
};

const obj2arr = (o) => {
   var res = [];
   Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
      res.push(typeof o[k] === 'object' ? obj2arr(o[k]) : o[k])
   });
   return res;
}

console.log(obj2arr(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var json = {
    "item1": {
         "11": {
             "name111": "name",
             "type112": "type"
         },
         "12": {
             "name121": "name",
             "type122": "type"
         }
    },
    "item2": {
         "21": {
             "name211": "name",
             "type212": "type"
         },
         "22": {
             "name221": "name",
             "type222": "type"
         }
    }
}

function copyObject(obj){
  var copy = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
      if(typeof(obj[key]) === 'object'){
        copy.push(copyObject(obj[key]));
      } else {
        copy.push(obj[key]);
      }
        
    }
    
    return copy;
}

console.log(copyObject(json));
```